# LINQ to Entities - query across relationships and filter

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am having a very difficult time with querying a set of related entities with LINQ and Lambda expressions.

I have four entities that are related as such ...

**Vehicles** 1:n **VehicleTypes** n:1 **Prices** 1:n **CustomerTypes**

I am trying to obtain a list of Prices for a given Vehicle and CustomerType. For example I would like to obtain all the Prices for a Ford Mustang (VehicleTypeId = 2). In those Prices I would like included the CustomerType (Government, Commercial, Retail) that the Price pertains to.

I thought I might be able to do the following ...

```
Prices.Include(p => p.VehicleTypes)
      .Include(p => p.CustomerTypes)
      .Where(p => p.VehicleTypes.Vehicles.Select(v => v.Id == 2)
```

However I get this error ...

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'bool'
```

I cannot seem to create a Where condition where I can filter the Id of the Vehicle to be purchased yet also include the CustomerType in the results.

EDIT: Just wanted to note that I have included `using System.Data.Entity` so I have access to the type safe Include extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the prices to that kind of vehicle and an specific customer type, you can filter as follows:

```
var prices= Prices.Include(p => p.VehicleTypes)
                  .Include(p => p.CustomerTypes)
                  .Where(p => p.VehicleTypes.Vehicles.Any(v => v.Id == 2)// With this condition you make sure that Mustang belong to this set of vehicles
                           && p.CustomerTypes.Type=="Commercial");
```

But in case you want to filter the vehicles in the result, you are going to need to project your query to an anonymous type or a DTO:

```
var query=  Prices.Include(p => p.VehicleTypes)
                  .Include(p => p.CustomerTypes)
                  .Where(p => p.VehicleTypes.Vehicles.Any(v => v.Id == 2)
                           && p.CustomerTypes.Type=="Commercial")
                  .Select(p=>new {CustomerType=p.CustomerTypes.Type, 
                                  Vehicles=p.VehicleTypes.Vehicles.Where(v => v.Id == 2)});
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It makes sense now that I see a properly formatted example. So it looks like if I need to have the Vehicle in the query results then I need to use the projection and again filter by the VehicleId? The previous filter does not apply?

Comment: you're welcome @webworm ;). Yes, unfourtunaly you need to project as I show above in your select, the first time is just to filter your `Price` entities